# Change values of last column

Tags: awk, sed, text-formatting

I have input like this i tried to replace the last Grade columns with 9 as AB, 12 as RE, 23 as A1, 34 as FA
is there any way  to change the grade columns with said values.

Input:

```
ST NAME MATHS   PHY ENG SCI    DATE       Grade
XXXX    123     0   53  12   12 20 2021    9
YYYY    10      76  90  34   13 20 2021    12
ZZZZZ   234     76  65  0    14 20 2021    23
DDDD    90      78  45  19   15 20 2021    34
```

expected output

```
ST NAME MATHS   PHY ENG SCI    DATE       Grade
XXXX    123     0   53  12   12 20 2021    AB
YYYY    10      76  90  34   13 20 2021    RE
ZZZZZ   234     76  65  0    14 20 2021    A1
DDDD    90      78  45  19   15 20 2021    FA
```

Comment: I don't understand - where do you take the exchange value from? How do you decide that 9 should be AB, 12 should be RE and so on? I'm also not sure if the input included both tables or only one, and which one.

Comment: Those are predefined valuve and Gradevcolumn will have 9 ,12,23,34.i need to change based on the predefined  values, i xan do this in sub in awk for an value but not for entire one

Comment: pre-defined from where? Where do you take the conversion of the number to the string from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `awk`. Put all four key-value-pairs in an array (`a`). Save last column from current row to a variable (`last`), remove last number from current row with `gsub` and append value from array to remaining row (`$0`):

```
awk 'BEGIN{ a[9]="AB"; a[12]="RE"; a[23]="A1"; a[34]="FA" };
     NR>1{ last=$NF; gsub(/[0-9]+$/,""); $0=$0 a[last] }
     { print }' file
```

Output:

```
ST NAME MATHS   PHY ENG SCI    DATE       Grade
XXXX    123     0   53  12   12 20 2021    AB
YYYY    10      76  90  34   13 20 2021    RE
ZZZZZ   234     76  65  0    14 20 2021    A1
DDDD    90      78  45  19   15 20 2021    FA
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple search and replace with `sed`. I assume that the columns are separated by several spaces.

```
sed 's/ 9$/ AB/; s/ 12$/ RE/; s/ 23$/ A1/; s/ 34$/ FA/' file
```

Output:

```
ST NAME MATHS   PHY ENG SCI    DATE       Grade
XXXX    123     0   53  12   12 20 2021    AB
YYYY    10      76  90  34   13 20 2021    RE
ZZZZZ   234     76  65  0    14 20 2021    A1
DDDD    90      78  45  19   15 20 2021    FA
```